# JSS7: Dahdli Card Configurations

Tags: asterisk, telecommunication, mobicents, ss7

Our SS7 service is integrated with telecom operator using "Digium TE420 E1 PRI" card through one digital E1 Cable 64 kbps.
The signaling is performed on channel 16.

This is steps we followed to start the sgw and activate SS7 links:

1-/etc/dahdi/system.conf:

```
span=1,1,0,ccs,hdb3,crc4
bchan=1-31
```

2-dahdi_cfg -vvv

3-in linksetmanager.xml:

```
<dahdilinkset name="dahdilinkset1" state="1" mode="1" opc="3008" apc="9008" ni="3" links="1">
    <link type="dahdilink" name="link1" state="1" mode="1" span="1" channelId="16" code="0" iOBufferSize="32"/>
</dahdilinkset>
```

4-run sgw

5-when execute command(linkset show/activate):

```
dahdilinkset1    dahdi    opc=3008        apc=9008        ni=3    state=UNAVAILABLE
    link1       span=1   channelId=1   code=0  state=UNAVAILABLE
    link2       span=1   channelId=16  code=0  state=UNAVAILABLE
```

6-And the output of SGW continuously print this lines:

```
 INFO  link1-0  - State changed in link. NOT_ALIGNED --> OUT_OF_SERVICE
 DEBUG link1-0  - (link1-0) Alignment not possible, initiating T17 for restart. Cause: T2 Expired.
 WARN  link1-0  - Timer T2 has expired, Alignment not possible.
```

FYI:Our server has (dahdi driver installed,libpri installed),(asterisk installed but it is stopped during running above steps)

FYI: Also, we test to activate link through Asterisk it work fine and receive calls from netwrok, but with different config of /etc/dahdi/system.conf as following:

```
span=1,1,0,ccs,hdb3,crc4
bchan=1-15,17-31
dchan=16
echocanceller=mg2,1-15,17-31
```

Is any thing wrong with this configuration, why we cannot align the SS7 Link?

Answer (score 0):

Try remove the link2 (link2       span=1   channelId=16  code=0  state=UNAVAILABLE) first if dahdi_tool show span1 is OK.